# What is automation testing and why do we need it?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management

I am new to the field of software testing. I would like to clarify the following basic things:

- As there were different types of testing process, we used to do manually enter testcases and write for an specific web applications...etc

As I currently understand it a tester would do the following types of manual testing

**Unit Testing**

**Integration Testing**

**System Testing**

Automating the process of web applications which we can't done manually (Eg regression testing) we use automation testing

I would like to know, what is the need for automation testing? Can anyone explain to me why automation testing should be used, and what is the need for an automation testing process?

Comment: Do you have any ideas why ?

Comment: @PhilKirkham i am beginner in this field so asked about to know what's the automation testing and why we need it

Comment: I understand, I just wanted to see if you had any opinions or thoughts

Comment: Manual testing is expensive.  Ask yourself, do we have the time or money to check all functionality each release manually?  Running automated tests is much cheaper and repeatable (if done right).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am going to vote -1 for the question.  There are way too many answers available just by typing "automated testing" or "test automation" on google e.g. http://support.smartbear.com/articles/testcomplete/manager-overview/.  If there is any other specific information you are looking for that you couldn't find while searching, please specify that.

Comment: Down-voting because this question is too broad and the answer can easily be found by Googling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Automation is using software to test software.  Testers use automation for the same kinds of reasons that other professions use automation: to do things in a more reliable, repeatable way than we could do with people.

There are other reasons why you might use automation.  For example, it may save time and/or save money, although if it is done in the wrong way or in the wrong circumstances, it may require even more time and more money than using people.

The categories of unit testing, integration testing, and system testing are orthogonal to whether you use automation.  Depending on the circumstances, you could do all, some, or none of that automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Test automation is a tool that can be used to remove the need for humans to have to execute the same checks over and over again as the software is changed as it is being developed.

I use the word "check" as automation doesn't do what a manual tester can do, it doesn't question, or think and make and disprove hypothesis on what bugs exist in software. It simply performs a set of pre-determined actions and verifies that expected behaviours occur.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post [about manual and automated tests](http://qablog.practitest.com/2011/05/manual-and-automated-tests/). It has some very interesting ideas on the subject.

Comment: Hello Hadar and welcome to SQA.SE. Consider expanding your answer by adding a brief summary of the referenced article. See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), section "Provide context for links". The article seems to contain a good content, but a brief summary would make your answer more valuable for those who read it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned in the question

> automating the process of web applications which we can't done manually(Eg regression testing) we use automation

Well there's nothing that can't be done manually or at least that's what I think.
But regression testing can most definitely be done manually.

By the way every testing is done by human - even what you consider automation. So I guess eventually its all manual.

But still you can use tools to help you with your testing. Where you would be doing something repeatedly you can write & run scripts for it.

Answer (score 1):

Automation Testing also known as Test Automation is the testing methodology, mainly in the field of software/application testing, in which the software testing life cycle(STLC) is carried out with automation so as to simplify the overall testing efforts with minimum scripting. Automation testing will help to automate some repetitive tasks, resulting in faster execution with better test coverage or outcomes.

Today, Automated software testing is considered as one of the most trending term in the field of software testing, as it is considered as one of the most efficient as well as effective software methodology, making the overall software development/testing life cycle better and taking it to some different level. These days as software testing is moving towards automation, most of the software testers as well as QAs are switching themselves from Manual testing to Automated testing.

Some of the reasons, why automation testing is considered as one of the trending methodology and has a vital scope:

1. Automation testing saves time as well as money.
2. It is considered as cost effective method,
3. Increases Test Coverage,
4. Makes testing more accurate,
5. Better Execution control,
6. Provides better and concise results,
7. Optimized resource usage, etc.

All these reasons make automation testing more effective as well as more efficient, resulting in better test outputs.

Comment: good one bro :)