# What are the things to care for while choosing an automation testing tool?

Tags: automated-testing, tools

I am new to software testing field ,I clarified for the need of automation tools [What is automation testing and why do we need it?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/what-is-automation-testing-and-why-do-we-need-it)

Now it arises me the following questions

**what were the things care for while choosing an automation testing tool for small/medium/web applications**?

Before choosing the automation tool I would like to know what were the thing to be noted before choosing an automation testing tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used lots of different tools - some commercial, some open-source, some home-grown - for test automation.  I usually use a mix of such tools in my overall automation efforts.

Over the years, I have found some nice-to-have features and attributes that I end up looking for, or building, as I assemble a new Test Automation Suite.  Some of these attributes are part of the tools themselves.  Others come about because of the way I assemble my Test Suites and tools into a complete package.

Some things are must-haves, and most are obvious:

- Run in my environment
- Automate my System-Under-Test
- Be able to "see" most of the objects in my System-Under-Test
- Usable by my test team
- Be affordable
- Be generally more efficient than strictly manual testing

Other things are nice-to-have:

- Detect changes in the System-Under-Test
- Create Smoke Tests which run after every build
- Run unattended
- Run overnight, and have a report ready the next morning
- Automate the boring, repetitive stuff
- Run predictably and repeatedly
- Randomize
- Perform timings
- Run some load, stress, and volume tests
- Isolate failures easily
- Run many tests, in spite of unexpected failures along the way
- Start wide, build depth later
- Automate what users do first (Getting Started Manual?)
- Isolate the maintenance effort
- Produce "readable" scripts
- Ability to reset the environment as needed
- Avoid false failures
- Extensible - since we cannot predict all uses
- Survive trivial changes to the System Under Test
- Validate during tests, and at the end as appropriate
- Ability to select and run subsets of the entire test suite
- Ability to select and skip particular tests
- Variable log levels (Verbose, Normal, Minimal)
- Minimize dependencies between scripts
- Minimize learning curve
- Minimize maintenance time
- Minimize post-run analysis time
- Minimize dependence on golden machines
- Record and Playback capability

You can find more details here:
http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/things-i-like-to-have-in-my-test.html

Comment: I would put extensibility higher up, as it allows you to add any of the higher features if they're missing, but otherwise I would say this matched my list perfectly